# Cannot login, getting error POST http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a login page with angular, but I am getting an error in web console:

> POST http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login 404 (Not Found)

I am following an example from: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/10/29/angular-7-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial#login-component-html . I have provided what I have thus far, but I am not sure what I am missing, would like to know how to fix this issue. When clicking "Login", I only receive an error message that says "[object Object]" with toastr.

**log-in.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../shared/user.model';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { UserService } from '../shared/user.service';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import {ToastrService} from 'ngx-toastr';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-log-in',
  templateUrl: './log-in.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./log-in.component.css']
})
export class LogInComponent implements OnInit {
  user:User;
  userLoginForm: FormGroup;
  loading = false;
  returnUrl: string;

  constructor(private userService:UserService, 
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private toastr: ToastrService
  ) { 
    //if (this.authService.currentUserValue) {
    //  this.router.navigate(['/']);
    //}
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createLoginForm();
  }

  createLoginForm() {
    this.userLoginForm = this.fb.group({
      UserName:  ['', Validators.required],
      Password:  ['', Validators.required]
  });
  this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
} 

  get f() { return this.userLoginForm.controls; }

  onSubmit() {
    //let request : User = new User();
    //request.UserName = this.userLoginForm.get('UserName').value;
    //request.Password = this.userLoginForm.get('Password').value;

    if (this.userLoginForm.valid) {
      this.loading = true;
      this.user = Object.assign({}, this.userLoginForm.value);
      this.authService.login(this.user)
        .pipe(first())
        .subscribe(
          (data:any) => {
            this.toastr.success("Login Successful");
          }
        , 
        error => {
        this.toastr.error(error);
        this.loading = false;
    }); 
  }
  }


}
```

**user.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { User } from './user.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  readonly rootUrl = "http://localhost:5000/" //connect to API
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  registerUser(user : User) : Observable<User> 
  {
    const body : User = {
      FirstName:user.FirstName,
      LastName:user.LastName,
      UserName: user.UserName,
      Password: user.Password,
      Email: user.Email,
      Token: user.Token
    }
    return this.http.post<User>(this.rootUrl + 'api/User/Register', body);
  }
}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { User } from '../shared/user.model';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt'; //npm install this

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl + 'auth/'; //in environment.ts api url
  jwtHelper = new JwtHelperService();
  decodedToken: any;
  currentUser: User;
  private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

public get currentUserValue(): User {
  return this.currentUserSubject.value;
}

login(model: any) {
  return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'login', model).pipe(
    map((response: any) => {
      const user = response;
      if (user) {
        localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user.user));
        this.decodedToken = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(user.token);
        this.currentUser = user.user;
      }
    })
  )
}

}
```

Comment: well, the error seems pretty clear, that endpoint doesn't exist?

Comment: I need to add something to user.service.ts ?

Comment: First question would be, what is your backend and does it have an endpoint like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your authentication service is calling an API that should (for a real implementation) return an authentication token of some sort.

Under "Running the Tutorial Example with a Real Backend API" section of that blog post you linked you will find instructions on how to implement such an API.

Another alternative is to enable the mocked service that is mentioned in the same series:

https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/05/02/angular-7-mock-backend-example-for-backendless-development